# Testing express server with mocha and supertest with async initializer calls the request twice

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to set up a testing framework for an express server and tests with require async initialization are giving me problems. Initially I tried to go with tape and supertest, but since tape seems to have poor support for async operations overall, I switched to mocha. Now I'm at least getting some error messages, but the test still does not work.

I'm trying to test a dummy ping endpoint /auth_ping, which should require a valid token to respond pong and should respond 403 otherwise. Currently the authentication is not yet implemented, so I'm trying to setup a test that initially fails because the server responds 200 and not 403 when requested without a token.

The first attempt of my test looks like this

```
'use strict';

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../server');
const keycloak = require('./util/keycloak-mock');

describe("authenticated ping", function() {
    it("should respond 403 when no token is provided", function(done) {

        keycloak.fetchToken()
            .then((token) => request(app)
                 .get("/auth_ping")
                 .expect(403)
                 .end(function (err, res) {
                   if (err) {
                       done(err)
                   };
                   done();
                 }));
    });
});
```

The test case begins with fetching a valid token from a mock authenticator with an asynchronous call. In this test the token is not used, but I want to make the call anyway to make sure the mock authenticator has been initialized. The token is anyway used in further test cases, so the fetch needs to work.

The output I get using this test is the following

```
  authenticated ping
Warning: superagent request was sent twice, because both .end() and .then() were called. Never call .end() if you use promises
Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent
superagent: double callback bug
(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 29
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/usr/src/app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:11:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    1) should respond 403 when no token is provided


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) authenticated ping
       should respond 403 when no token is provided:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/usr/src/app/test/index.js)
```

I'm not really sure how the flow works here and why the request is made twice. Yes, I am calling both then() and end(), but since then() is not related to supertest I don't know how it could influence the request. Also end() seems to be the only place for me to call done() for mocha, so I don't see how the test could ever work without it.

Anyway, I tried to modify the test by removing the end() call:

```
'use strict';

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../server');
const keycloak = require('./util/keycloak-mock');

describe("authenticated ping", function() {
    it("should respond 403 when no token is provided", function(done) {

        keycloak.fetchToken()
            .then((token) => request(app)
                 .get("/auth_ping")
                 .expect(403)
            );
    });
});
```

After this the output is this:

```
  authenticated ping
(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expected 403 "Forbidden", got 200 "OK"
    at Test._assertStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:268:12)
    at Test._assertFunction (/usr/src/app/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:283:11)
    at Test.assert (/usr/src/app/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:173:18)
    at Server.localAssert (/usr/src/app/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1619:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    1) should respond 403 when no token is provided


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) authenticated ping
       should respond 403 when no token is provided:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/usr/src/app/test/index.js)
```

In the stack trace I can see that the expected test result is reached, since the respond 200 is compared to the expected 403 and that part now looks fine, but after that the test case timeouts and fails because of that. I think this was to be expected, since `done()` was never called and I feel I understand what happens here.

But what happens in my first attempt and how to I resolve that? To be it looks more valid than the latter attempt, but I cannot understand why the request is being sent twice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I sorted the problem out now and it has nothing to do with the asynchronous call.

The right way to write the method seems to be

```
'use strict';

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../server');
const keycloak = require('./util/keycloak-mock');

describe("authenticated ping", function() {
    it("should respond 403 when no token is provided", function(done) {

        keycloak.fetchToken()
            .then((token) => request(app)
                 .get("/auth_ping")
                 .expect(403)
                 .end(done);
            );
    });
});
```

It seems that the short tutorial I found on using supertest with mocha included what might be a bad practice by suggesting to add my own method to the end() function. This works fine when the test succeeds, but breaks if the test fails on one of the expects.

I didn't find it anywhere written, but what I tested it seems that you have to either to end the command chain with *end(done)* or add done as an additional parameter to the last expect in the chain (but not to any of the earlier ones). So instead of adding the *end(done)* I could also leave that out and end the chain with *expect(403, done)*. For now I prefer explicit end though as it is then easier to add additional expects to the chain wihtout breaking anything.